# Chrome Extension get meta keywords

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, meta-tags

I am making a Google Chrome Extension, and maybe I am stupid, but I just cant find out how to get the "keywords" from the background(current) page.. And with "keywords" I am referring to the meta tags. Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean the background page (does it have keywords?), or the page where this extension is running?  Why doesn't Josh's answer work?  (And don't put everything in bold.  It's annoying.)

Comment: By "background page", do you mean [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)? If so, take a look at [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: So with background page I am think:

if you are surfing http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/ and you wanna look inside the <header> tags and the meta tags <meta name="Keywords" content="...something...., Something other.."> 

Josh answer dont work simply because thats the current html doc.. your own html popup file. No more bold ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jQuery, I don't see why $('meta') wouldn't work? With vanilla Javascript, document.getElementsByTagName('meta').